# How to swap two elements of an mpl::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

I'm writing a template function which should swap two elements of a `boost::mpl::vector` (similarly to `std::swap`). The difficult part is there is no concept of a variable during compile time. I have written a draft but I wonder if there are better ways to approach this.

My current code sketch extracts an integral index from iterators and performs a copy of the sequence type with the elements swapped. The question is - can this be done better:

```
#include <boost/mpl/distance.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/comparison.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/equal.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/clear.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/next_prior.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/or.hpp>

using boost::mpl::distance;
using boost::mpl::begin;
using boost::mpl::end;
using boost::mpl::next;
using boost::mpl::at;
using boost::mpl::or_;
using boost::mpl::int_;
using boost::mpl::eval_if;
using boost::mpl::greater;
using boost::mpl::equal;
using boost::mpl::clear;
using boost::mpl::push_back;


namespace boost { namespace mpl {

template<template<typename, typename> class T, class A, class B>
struct eval2 {
    typedef typename T<typename A::type, typename B::type>::type type;
};


namespace details {

    template <typename Dest_seq, typename It_end, typename It_first, typename It_second, typename It_idx>
    struct copy_and_swap {
    private:
        typedef typename eval_if< is_same<It_idx, It_first>,
                                  eval2<push_back, Dest_seq, deref<It_second> >,
                                  eval_if<is_same<It_idx, It_second>,
                                          eval2<push_back, Dest_seq, deref<It_first> >,
                                          eval2<push_back, Dest_seq, deref<It_idx> >
                                         >
                                >::type Limit_idx;
        typedef typename next<It_idx>::type it_idx_next;

    public:
        // next step
        typedef typename eval_if <is_same<it_idx_next, It_end>,
                                  New_seq,
                                  copy_and_swap<New_seq, 
                                                It_end, 
                                                It_first, 
                                                It_second, 
                                                it_idx_next>
                                 >::type type;
    };

} // namespace details


template<typename Seq, typename Begin, typename End>
struct swap {
  private:
    typedef typename begin<Seq>::type                it_begin;
    typedef typename end<Seq>::type                  it_end;
    // get an empty container type "compatible" with Seq
    typedef typename clear<Seq>::type        Container_t;
    // border case - swap self
    typedef typename is_same<Begin, End>::type   swap_self;
    // border case - less than 2 elements in sequence
    typedef typename less<size<Seq>, int_<2> >::type    no_swap;

  public:
    // perform the element swapping
    typedef typename eval_if <or_<swap_self, no_swap>,
                              Seq,
                              details::copy_and_swap<Container_t,
                                                     it_end,
                                                     Begin,
                                                     End,
                                                     it_begin >
                             >::type type;
};

} // namespace mpl
} // namespace boost
```

This metafunction can be used like:

```
struct value_printer {
    template< typename U > void operator()(U x) {
        std::cout << x << ',';
    }
};



typedef vector_c<int, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4>::type    test_vect;
typedef begin<test_vect>::type    it_beg;
typedef advance<it_beg, int_<2> >::type    it;
typedef advance<it_beg, int_<5> >::type    it_stop;
typedef m_swap<test_vect, it_stop, it>::type    result;
boost::mpl::for_each< result >( value_printer() );
```

and the result is 1,2,4,6,5,3,

Comment: `swap` implies the existence of a mutable object, and there are no mutable entities in template metaprogramming. What is it that you want to *swap* the description of *equivalent to std::swap and std::vector* cannot really be applied here. Can you provide the set of inputs and the expected output of the opreation?

Comment: @dribeas Yes you are right - mutable object is not available in metaprograming. What I want is to only mimic the behavior of the runtime version (have the same side effect). The input should be the (type) sequence and two iterators - the output should be a new (type) sequence with a different order of elements (swapped). Currently I recreating the new sequence from scratch and I wonder if there is any place for improvements.

Comment: @Marcin : Interesting problem, I'll have a look at it this weekend and see if I can come up with anything better (no time today unfortunately). :-]

Comment: I've updated the code so it has no compile errors. The eval2 template is only used to delay the type computations of the push_back function's arguments,

Comment: I agree with @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, your requirements are not very clear. You say in your comment that you want your swap to have "the same side effect"; that does not make sense since there is no side effects in TMP. Then you say that your input is a sequence and two iterators, but you don't explain what the iterators mean. Could you give an example of how you would use your swap algorithm?

Comment: @Luc Touraille By saying "side effect" I wanted to make the explanation shorter. I ment that the resulting type should be a type sequence similar to the one provided, but with two elements in different order. The iterators are boost iterator concepts (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/iterators.html)

Comment: I've updated the code examples provided in the question. I don't think there is much place for improvement left, so I'm going to close the question tomorrow evening if no better suggestions appear.

Comment: you can use xor to swap without a var, but not sure if this helps you much.

Comment: Your edit clarifies the question: you want to swap *two* elements of an `mpl::vector`, not "swap values of a `boost::mpl::vector` (similarly to `std::swap` and `std::vector`)". Swapping two `std::vector`s means exchanging their contents, which is not what you are trying to achieve. That being said, your solution seems reasonable, but I'll still post a (possibly) simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using only MPL metafunctions, without explicit recursion. The idea is to start by copying all the values between the beginning of the sequence and the first value to swap, insert the second value, copy the middle, insert the first value, and finally copy the end.

A disadvantage of this method is that the iterators must form a valid range: `Second` must not be before `First`. I don't think there is any way to overcome this restriction with this solution, but it does not seem like an unbearable requirement.

Here is the code:

```
// Precondition: [First, Second] is a valid range in Seq
template< typename Seq, typename First, typename Second >
struct swap {
  private:
    typedef typename begin< Seq >::type begin;
    typedef typename end< Seq >::type   end;

    typedef typename clear< Seq >::type empty_container;

    // Insert values from begin to first
    typedef typename
        copy<
            iterator_range< begin, First >,
            back_inserter< empty_container >
        >::type prefix;

    // Insert second value 
    typedef typename
        push_back<
            prefix, typename
            deref< Second >::type
        >:: type prefixSecond;

    // Insert values from first+1 to second
    typedef typename
        copy<
            iterator_range< typename next< First >::type, Second >,
            back_inserter< prefixSecond >
        >::type prefixSecondMiddle;

    // Insert first value
    typedef typename
        push_back<
            prefixSecondMiddle, typename
            deref< First >::type
        >::type prefixSecondMiddleFirst;

    // Insert values from second+1 to end
    typedef typename
        copy<
            iterator_range< typename next< Second >::type, end >,
            back_inserter< prefixSecondMiddleFirst >
        >::type prefixSecondMiddleFirstSuffix;

  public:
    typedef prefixSecondMiddleFirstSuffix type;
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution proposal. I wasn't aware of the iterator_range template. Te requirement for ordering of 'First' and 'Second' can be relaxed by comparing their distance from the beginning of Seq and swaping them if required. Your solution has the advantage, that it will require less recursion depth.

Comment: @Marcin: I feel a bit ashamed for not thinking about that! I considered computing the distance between the two iterators, but not with the beginning of the sequence...